# Select max from several columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing code to select patients that die within 30 days of a hospital discharge, my issue is that when I have a patient with multiple discharges within that 30 day tolerance it pulls back multiple rows! I've tried to solve this using max discharge date, which worked, yet when I add extra columns it seems to pull certain elements from other rows. Here is my code:

```
    SELECT  MAX(IPS.disch_dttm)               [Discharge Datetime]
            ,MAX(IPS.IP_SPELL_ID)             [Spell ID]    
            ,pat.PAS_ID                       [K Number]
            ,MAX(IPS.DIS_WARD_ID)             [Ward ID]
            ,DSSU.SU_DESCRIPTION              [Discharging Ward]

    FROM Pat_spell AS IPS
    LEFT JOIN PATIENT PAT       WITH (NOLOCK) ON PAT.DIM_PATIENT_ID = IPS.DIM_PATIENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN SPECIALTY SPEC    WITH (NOLOCK) ON SPEC.DIM_SPECIALTY_ID = IPS.DIM_DIS_SPECT_ID
    LEFT JOIN SERVICE_UNIT DSSU WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.DIM_DIS_WARD_ID = DSSU.DIM_SSU_ID

    WHERE (IPS.DISCH_DTTM <= PAT.DEATH_DTTM + 30)
    AND IPS.DIM_DIS_SPECT_ID = '7195'
    AND IPS.DISCH_DTTM BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '30/06/2014'

    GROUP BY pat.PAS_ID
            ,pat.DEATH_DTTM
            ,IPS.DIM_PATIENT_ID
            ,DSSU.SSU_DESCRIPTION

    ORDER BY pat.PAS_ID
```

Here is output from the above code for a single row that I've been using to debug:

```
Disch Date  Event_ID   Unique ID  Ward ID   Discharging Ward
2014-06-14  8366113    A123456   77085       WardA
```

The above gets the ward ID correct, but the "Discharging Ward" is wrong. Also the Event_ID corresponds with a previous attendance. What I'm trying to achieve is to pull only the most recent event within 30 days of a time of death, with 'Event ID' as my unique ID. This is what the output would look like if I wanted multiple rows:

```
  Disch Date  Event ID  Unique ID    Ward ID    Discharging Ward
1 2014-06-14    8208846  A123456       77085     Ward B       
2 2014-05-16    8366113  A123456       77036     Ward A
```

This is what my output should look like:

```
  Disch Date  Event_ID   Unique ID  Ward ID   Discharging Ward
2014-06-14  8208846    A123456   77085      Ward B
```

So to sum up, my code pulls the correct "discharge date", the correct "Ward ID" but seems to pull the rest from other rows in the table. Apologies for the huge ask - any help would be appreciated, or if this has been explored to death, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you littering you query with NOLOCK? Is accuracy not important for this query? This would be a lot easier to help with some ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: A common approach is to simplify this SQL to select the unique ID of the latest row. Then, INNER JOIN to this SQL using a query that pulls the other information you want. I can probably write up a sample if you need.

Comment: @SeanLange `NOLOCK` makes it go faster, right? MAGIC TURBO BUTTON FTW!!!!

Comment: @swasheck I hope your aren't serious!!!

Comment: @SeanLange not. at. all.

Comment: Well in honesty it "can" make it faster....at a serious cost. ;)

Comment: @Mrniceguy - here are a couple links about how horrible that particular "go fast" button is. http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Comment: Wow, you fellas really hate the old nolock eh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified version of what you need looks like this...

```
SELECT  [DETAIL INFO, no need to MAX or GROUP BY]
FROM Pat_spell AS IPS
LEFT JOIN PATIENT PAT       WITH (NOLOCK) ON PAT.DIM_PATIENT_ID = IPS.DIM_PATIENT_ID
LEFT JOIN SPECIALTY SPEC    WITH (NOLOCK) ON SPEC.DIM_SPECIALTY_ID = IPS.DIM_DIS_SPECT_ID
LEFT JOIN SERVICE_UNIT DSSU WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.DIM_DIS_WARD_ID = DSSU.DIM_SSU_ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PatientID, MAX(IPS.disch_dttm) AS DischargeDt
    FROM [AllMyTables]
    WHERE (IPS.DISCH_DTTM <= PAT.DEATH_DTTM + 30)
    AND IPS.DIM_DIS_SPECT_ID = '7195'
    AND IPS.DISCH_DTTM BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '30/06/2014'
) t1 ON PAT.PatientID = t1.PatientID AND IPS.disch_dttm = t1.DischargeDt
ORDER BY pat.PAS_ID
```

Since the INNER SQL is returning 1 row per patient, there is no need to group on the OUTER SQL.

If I had more data to work with, I might be able to stitch together the full SQL, but maybe this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Worked a charm, and now i have a better understanding of inner queries. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the max of each field independently. If you want the row that corresponds with the latest discharge date, you need to row_number it in Descending order, then select where that =1.
We do the same type query for 30 day re-admits.
So something like

```
WITH 
LastDischargeCTE
AS
(SELECT pat.PAS_ID [K Number], IPS.disch_dttm [Discharge Datetime], (IPS.IP_SPELL_ID) [Spell ID] 
,(IPS.DIS_WARD_ID) [Ward ID]
,DSSU.SU_DESCRIPTION [Discharging Ward]
,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY pat.PAS_ID ORDER BY IPS.disch_dttm DESC) AS DischargeSequence

FROM Pat_spell
LEFT JOIN PATIENT PAT               WITH (NOLOCK) ON PAT.DIM_PATIENT_ID = IPS.DIM_PATIENT_ID
LEFT JOIN SPECIALTY SPEC            WITH (NOLOCK) ON SPEC.DIM_SPECIALTY_ID = IPS.DIM_DIS_SPECT_ID
LEFT JOIN SERVICE_UNIT DSSU WITH (NOLOCK) ON IPS.DIM_DIS_WARD_ID = DSSU.DIM_SSU_ID
WHERE (IPS.DISCH_DTTM <= PAT.DEATH_DTTM + 30)
AND IPS.DIM_DIS_SPECT_ID = '7195'
AND IPS.DISCH_DTTM BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '30/06/2014'
)
SELECT *
FROM LastDischargeCTE 
WHERE DischargeSequence =1
```